# When I put data on :notes and :place, the validation still fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessor

I think, this code is correct but I don't know what happen? Here's my code:

registration.rb :

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :create_registration, :is_contact_registration, :is_appointment_registration

  validates :client_id, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true
  validates :contact_thru, presence: true
  validates :purpose_message, presence: true,   :unless => :is_appointment_registration
  validates :action_needed, presence: true,     :unless => :is_appointment_registration
  validates :date_created, presence: true
  validates :owner_id, presence: true
  validates :status, presence: true
  validates :notes, presence: true  

end
```

My controller,

```
  def create
    binding.pry
    @registration = Registration.new(record_params)
    @registration.owner_id = current_user.id

    @registration.is_appointment_registration = true
    if @registration.save
      render json: @registration, status: :created, location: @registration
    else
      render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end
```

The problem is, when I put data on `:notes` and `:place`, the validation still fails.

Comment: What is the `exact error` you getting?

Comment: validates :place, presence: true
validates :notes, presence: true

in that params, even if i put some data, it says it's nil.

Comment: Edited with more understandable wording.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is, when I put data on :notes and :place, it returns error even I have data input.

Your `attr_accessor` does not include `:notes` or `:place`. Unless you have those attributes as database columns, you'll need to declare them as virtual attributes in the `attr_accessor` block:

```
attr_accessor :create_registration, :is_contact_registration, :is_appointment_registration, :notes, :place
```

Comment: Damn! I was just too lazy to scroll the scroll-bar.

Comment: Don't know if it's the right answer; just an observation

Comment: Not the right answer. Rails 4 has done away with attr_accessor.

Comment: 1. [`attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is a **ruby** method (independent of Rails). 2. Rails 3 removed support for `attr_accessible`, *not* `attr_accessor`. Can you provide me with a resource to demonstrate your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 has done away with attr_accessor (located on the model) in favor of Strong Parameters, included on the controller. You'll need to update your code, moving all field from attr_accessor to params in your controller, like this:

```
def create
    ModelName.new(controller_name_params)
    ...
end

private
def controller_name_params
        params.require(:controller_name).permit(
            :field1,
            :field2
        )
    end
```

And like @Rich says, make sure to add all fields to params that you want your users to be able to change.

More information in the docs, here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html